# Nested foreach issues

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a script to print appointments from a mysql db, There is 2 foreach loops, one to print the date, and one to print the appointments related to that date. However the second foreach loop only prints the first item from each date.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
require('sessions.inc.php');
Include('config.inc.php');

if(!isLoggedIn())
{
   echo("not logged in");
}
else
{
//form
   echo('  <html>
        <center><h1>Add new Appontment</h1></center>
        <form name="login" action="diary.php" method="post">
        Date (YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="text" name="date"/><br>
        Time (HH-MM-SS):<input type="text" name="time"/><br>
        Description:<input type="descrip" name="descrip"/><br>
        Place:<input type="place" name="place"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="sumbit"/>
        </form>
        </html>
        ');

//Connect to DB
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);


//Get Data from DB

$query = "SELECT id,title,date,time,place FROM tbl_diary GROUP BY date;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//Get Data from form
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
$time = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['time']);
$descrip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descrip']);
$place = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['place']);

//insert into DB
if (isset($_POST['date'],$_POST['time'],$_POST['descrip'],$_POST['place']))
{
    $insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_diary (date,time,title,place) VALUES ('$date','$time','$descrip','$place')";

        if (!mysql_query($insert))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    echo ('New appontment at'.$_POST['place'].'added, On'.$_POST['date'].".<br>");
    echo ('<a href="./index.php?page=diary">Please click to reload page</a>');
}

//Intizlize array
$array = array();


//Display appontments


while($input = mysql_fetch_array($result))

 {
    if (!isset($array[$input['date']]))
    {
        $array[$input['date']] = array();
    }
    //put to end of array
    $array[$input['date']] []= $input;
}
//The first for each prints each date, The second prints the times.
foreach ($array as $TheDate => $items)
{
$therealdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($TheDate));
//welcome to europe MySql

    echo '<h1>'.$therealdate.'</h1>';
    echo "<ul>";

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        echo "<li>{$item['time']}: {$item['title']} "."@ {$item['place']}</li>";
    }

echo "</ul>";
}
//exit
echo ('<a href="./main.php">Return to main</a>');
}
?>
```

Comment: Actually just fixed this, It was the added GROUP BY date on the SQL query, Cant work out how to delete this though...

Comment: should be a delete link underneath the question unless maybe its disabled for n00bz :)

Comment: @Andrew, that code could use some cleaning. echo is not a function, include/require should be used as functions. **shrugs**

Comment: Thanks, I've cleaned it up, Any other feedback?

Comment: also under my question i have link edit flag

Comment: @Khez include/require don't have to be used as functions, and can cause unexpected result if treated as such. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php See Example 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in your mysql query string.

```
SELECT id,title,date,time,place FROM tbl_diary GROUP BY date;
```

This query grab only a row if date are the same.

Try this:

```
SELECT id,title,date,time,place FROM tbl_diary;
```